# Hibernate Validator and apache bval - which validator to load?

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

Project has both `bval` and `hibernate validator 5.3.6Final`.

bval comes from a 3rd party jar dependency

When trying to load Validator - its defaulting to bval and fails at validation constraint defined by hibernate annotation.

```
final Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
        ValidatorFactory cf = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        final Set<ConstraintViolation<AdminLoginFormImpl>> violations = validator.validate(this)
```

1. How to load exclusively hibernate validator ?
2. Can they even co-exist ?

Exception seen ::

```
No compliant org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length ConstraintValidator found for annotated element of type java.lang.String

javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: No compliant org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length ConstraintValidator found for annotated element of type java.lang.String

org.apache.bval.jsr.job.ComputeConstraintValidatorClass.findAnnotatedElementValidator(ComputeConstraintValidatorClass.java:171)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, your code uses one of the Hibernate Validator-specific constraints so using Apache BVal won't work.

If your code doesn't use any Apache BVal-specific features, I would stick to Hibernate Validator and exclude Apache Bval from the dependencies.

In any case, only one of the implementations will be used so you should only have one.